# Kafka Integration with AWS GLUE

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-glue-spark

Could not find any specific Group for this particular integration.

I am working for a retail organisation and trying to do direct integration of Kafka streams with Glue. I mean putting Kafka Topic as input Source to AWS Glue. I am using Apache Kafka 2.12.

I am coming to this group for some help if anyone has worked on this integration Pattern.  My Problems during this integration testing as below

1) When I create a Connection to Kafka in AWS Glue Console, 'Test Connection' Option is disabled (greyed out) on AWS Glue Console. So not sure if Connection I created is okay or not.

2) In my setup - input source is Kafka / Topic with messages in JSON Format. Target I get kept as S3/csv format with default mapping of fields between source and Target. I opted SparkStreaming for the job Type.

Main issue is AWS Glue Job runs continuously for hours and hours but does not generate any output. Seems like job/pyspark script is not able to read  from Kafka. Even in the logs I am not able to make out if it is connecting to kafka server or not

3) When Kafka Stream is used an input source to AWS Glue - Table/Schema in AWS Glue Database needs to be created manually which we did. but I am not sure if the table schema is created correctly or not as I have noticed below in the job log (isRegisteredWithLF: false)

2020-05-29 09:46:34,047 INFO [Thread-9] glue.GlueContext (GlueContext.scala:getCatalogSource(176)) - getCatalogSource: catalogId: null, nameSpace: poc-glue-athena-database, tableName: kafka_stream, isRegisteredWithLF: false

4) Can someone confirm if AWS Glue job use KSql (a kafka component)  for anything internally. I am getting the below warning for the port 8088 (which I suppose is used for KSQL Server ) in kafka. I can understand this - why it is coming because i have not setup KSQL instance in my setup. since it is Warning - i assume this should not be a big issue for AWS Glue Job not to work.
2020-05-29 09:46:36,201 WARN [Thread-9] client.YarnClient (YarnClient.java:makeRestApiRequest(66)) - The GET request failed for the URL http://0.0.0.0:8088/ws/v1/cluster/apps/application_1590745365782_0001
com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 0.0.0.0:8088 [/0.0.0.0] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Regards
Sanjeev

Answer (score 0):

I have been using bootstrap server(:9094) for  TLS and data was not being read in GLUE. But when I used bootstrap server  for plain text(kafka.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:9092). It is being read.